# Remove items already owned from library

Tags: patterns

My scenario is:

You have a library of courses. These courses can be added to your own "my courses". When you already have a course in your "my courses" should it still display in the library (potentially greyed out)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm of the opinion that owned courses should not be greyed out - that may indicate to the user that the class is "disabled" (not available, cancelled, you don't have the prereqs, etc). I'd leave them in the list with other visual cues to help the user keep score of what they have and what they still need to add.

Comment: Good point about apparently disabling the course could indicate something else other than "already added" - "unavailable" being the most obvious reason.

Comment: I think you hit the point as to why I was feeling uncomfortable with greying them out. I will go down the route of using some kind of "added" indication to the element.

Answer (score 6):

If you are going to display the courses already added you need some visual indication that the user has added the course to their list.

Greying out is one option - but that has it's drawback as it could (and perhaps should) indicate that the course is unavailable for some reason (see [melee's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/20133/60)). A better alternative would be to replace the "Add Course" button with a "Remove Course" button.

Hiding the courses could be problematical as (depending on what information you show for courses in the users "My Courses" list) some information might not be available any more. This could cause frustration if users want to compare the information with other courses.